# Problem with iterating throught DOM using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have html with such structure:

```
<div id="info">
     <h1>Some text</h1>
</div>
<div class="box_con">
    <div id="list">
        <dl>
            <dt>《Library of Heaven“s Path》 Volume 1</dt>
            <dd> <a style="" href="1300359.html">1 Swindler</a></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$volume_titles = [];
$title = $doc->getElementById('info')->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
$volume_list = $doc->getElementById('list')->getElementsByTagName('dl');
```

And I dont know how to iterate this `dl` element to retrieve `<a>` href and content. I have already tried a lot of loops.

```
    $el = $volume_list->firstChild;
    do {
        var_dump($el);
    } while ($el = $el->nextSibling);



    $length = $volume_list->length;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $node = $volume_list->childNodes->item($i);
        var_dump($node);
        die();
    }


        foreach ($volume_list->childNodes as $volume) {
        //var_dump($volume_list->getElementsByTagName('dd')->item(0)->nodeValue);
        var_dump($volume);
        die();
    }
```

But nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that when you use `getElementsByTagName()`, this returns a list of nodes (actually a `DOMNodeList`).  So when you want to access (for example) the first item for that tag, you will need to reference the first item in an array.

If you extended your initial code to get the nested tag elements, you could end up with the following code, which always uses `[0]` on the result of `getElementsByTagName()` to pick out the first item.

```
$title = $doc->getElementById('info')->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
$volume_list = $doc->getElementById('list')->getElementsByTagName('dl');

$a = $volume_list[0]->getElementsByTagName('dd')[0]->getElementsByTagName('a');

echo $a[0]->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Thank u so much! It works! So all that I need now is just to loop it by indices

Comment: You can use a `foreach()` loop on the nodelist which is quite common.